# Javascript if else timer on specific days

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using this code

Here is a codePen to see it. https://codepen.io/celli/pen/jaBrpP But the console doesn't seem to log any of my if else statements, except for the first log. What is wrong in the code, where it is not firing each of my conditions ?

```js
function showDateContent() {
  var d = new Date();
  console.log(d.getDate(), d.getMonth());
  if (d.getDate() >= 4 && d.getDate() <= 17 && d.getMonth() + 1 == 12) {
    console.log("date is between 12/4 and 12/17");
  } else if (d.getDate() >= 18 && d.getDate() <= 30 && d.getMonth() + 1 == 12) {
    console.log("date is between 12/18 and 12/30");
  } else if (d.getDate() >= 31 && d.getMonth() + 1 == 12 || d.getDate() >= 1 && d.getMonth() + 1 == 1) {
    console.log("date is after 12/31/2017 or we are in the New Year of 2018");
  }
}
showDateContent();
```

Comment: Why would the code go into the `else` blocks?  This is November, not December.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: such a date never occurs.

Comment: For today the first log will be "17 10" and that will never enter into any other logs in that code. sorry for the short comment @mplungjan

Comment: @AdarshMohan -  var d = new Date(2017,11,15); will show the first - so such a date DOES occur - Next month

Comment: @mplungjan : we are in the present `new Date();`

Comment: the question is with `new Date();` not with `new Date(2017, 11, 15);`

Comment: I too was only saying about that.. the present is always present.. and future cannot be present..:P

Comment: which future are you making sense of?? November will come again in the future..:P

Answer (score 1):

Because you are also checking if the month is `12` or `1`, while we are currently the eleventh month of the year.

Comment: Vote to close??

Answer (score 0):

Current month is 11, `getMonth()` is  0 based index and offset by 1

```
if(d.getDate() >= 4 && d.getDate()<= 17 && d.getMonth()+1 == 11)
```

```js
function showDateContent(){
var d=new Date();

console.log(d.getDate(), d.getMonth());

if(d.getDate() >= 4 && d.getDate()<= 17 && d.getMonth()+1 == 11){
    console.log("date is between 12/4 and 12/17");


} else if(d.getDate() >= 18 && d.getDate()<= 30 && d.getMonth()+1 == 11){
    console.log("date is between 12/18 and 12/30");


} else if(d.getDate() >= 31 && d.getMonth()+1 == 12 || d.getDate() >= 1 && d.getMonth()+1 == 1){
    console.log("date is after 12/31/2017 or we are in the New Year of 2018");

}
}

showDateContent();
```